# Delay MathJax with jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, delay, mathjax

With jQuery I run a function on-the-go which causes MathJax on the page to render. In this style:

```
function renderMath() {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
}
```

I would like to delay it a bit, though, since the page jumps a lot if several function calls are made quickly after one another. How can the function be delayed in its responds? The `setTimeout` function in jQuery has no effect:

```
function renderMath() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
  }, 2000);
}
```

Here it is set with 2 seconds delay for exaggeration, but it has no effect.
**What other option do I have for delaying the function?**